# Display image if present in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datagrid

I am writing a program to display text and image associated with the text. The nature of data is such that I may or may not have image for every text. This is information is in collection of objects. Each object has text and path of image. If image is not there then path is empty. The class for the object is

```
public class MyInfo
{
    public DateTime EntryDate { set; get; }
    public string NoteText { set; get; }
    public string ImagePath { set; get; }
}
```

I used DataGrid to display the information. 1st column shows text and the second shows image. If there is no image then the 2nd column is empty. This does not look nice and customer is asking to change the UI so that it should take the full row if there is no image. Also he wants to have clear separator between the rows. I already have alternating colors but does not go well with the both text and image in place.

Please suggest how to enhance the grid. If DataGrid is not the right control then what is the other control/approach to resolve it.

Thanks

Comment: you can add value converter for that particular column and on the basis of value true or false you can set visibility of column

Comment: Thanks. Never thought about converters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would a ListBox and use the ListBox.ItemTemplate to define how the row will look. This will give greater flexibility and better achieve what you want. As Ashok said you will want to use a value converter to convert a empty string into a "Collapsed" visibility option.

Converter example:

```
public class EmptyStringToCollapsedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = (value as string);
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DataGrid`, I suggest to use the `ListBox` with a `DataTemplate`, in a way similar to this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyInfoCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=EntryDate}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=NoteText}" />
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox .ItemTemplate>
</ListBox >
```

Where `MyInfoCollection` is an ObservableCollection of `MyInfo` objects.